# I am searching for a word or phrase that describes reflected light, dancing light etc

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am trying to find a word or short phrase that conveys the idea of reflected light, dancing light, flickering light. It is for an artistic project to name an artwork piece I am constructing where light throws patterns and colours onto a wall or surface through transparent colored film.

Comment: Yes I've tried the usual suspects like the thesaurus but I'm trying to find a phrase which conveys the way the light reflects patterns onto a surface that can be used for the name of a product!

Comment: @Pip That sounds like a writing request. We don't do those here.

Comment: Perhaps synonyms of *capricious* would lead you to inspiration. Without seeing the nature of the light, it's a bit difficult to ascertain the mood of the word you're looking for.

Answer (score 10):

coruscate

> intr.v.
>   1. To give forth flashes of light; sparkle and glitter: diamonds coruscating in the candlelight.
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/coruscate)
>
> verb
>   literary
>  (of light) flash or sparkle. 
> ‘the light was coruscating
>   through the walls’
>  [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/coruscate)
>   (Thanks to ubi hatt for getting this definition)

If you're familiar with Star Wars lore, you may have heard of a planet called Coruscant, which is the adjective form of the word.

You might also like scintillate:

> intr.v.
>   1. To send forth light in flashes; sparkle
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/scintillate)

Similar and simpler words like glimmer and sparkle may mean the same thing. I'm unsure if you need something that specifically means reflectance and projection of light onto objects (walls), as you mentioned. If so, none of these words capture all of that I'm afraid. I doubt there'd be one word that would encompass all of those meanings.

Given that many of these words are so similar, it may come down to whichever word you think sounds nicer.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to find something that does imply the reflection of the light and the patterns and colors it throws! I never thought it would be so tricky to find the perfect phrase!! Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: I have a feeling I got upvotes for the Star Wars reference. I don't see why coruscate is any more an accurate word for the OP's needs than any other word like shimmer or glimmer. That, and it's a hella arcane word.

Comment: Provide the link of [oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/coruscate). It particularly states (of light).

Comment: @ubihatt Yeah, I guess, but so do other words mention "light". And also, I don't want to selectively choose a definition from one particular dictionary which reinforces my answer's suitability. Although I can't deny I've done it before.

Comment: +1 for obscure words!  Sometimes, an artistic title needs an obscure word or two.  The OP will have to decide if the Star Wars connection is good or bad in relation to their work, but it was probably good to mention it (I didn't actually know the planet's name, so I would have completely missed the connection).

Answer (score 4):

You mention reflected light but note later that the light will be transmitted *through* a film. Therefore, you may find the term **kaleidoscopic** useful; the term most specifically describes a assemblage of different and varying colors, and the origin of course is the [kaleidoscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaleidoscope), an optical instrument that could employ either reflection or transmission or both.

[image]
(Source: https://kaleidoscopetherapy.co.uk)

Comment: This picture shows a number of people lying on the floor facing _away_ from the kaleidoscopic spectacle; how bizarre!

Comment: @Timbo I don't see that image, but I'm guessing that they are looking at a projection on the ceiling.

Answer (score 4):

The rippling patterns of light you get, for example, at the bottom of a swimming pool are called [caustics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caustic_(optics)):

> In optics, a caustic or caustic network[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caustic_(optics)) is the envelope of light rays reflected or refracted by a curved surface or object, or the projection of that envelope of rays on another surface.

Comment: More specifically, a caustic is where light is either reflected or refracted such that it is concentrated in an area that is brighter than the surroundings -- so it's the bright lines that are seen on the bottom of a swimming pool, but not the space between them (even though that space also is receiving reflected or refracted rays).

Comment: Be advised that this word could be contextually unsuitable.  ‘Caustic’ also meaning to chemically burn, damage, corrode …  Some insults are described as “caustic remarks” occasionally.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that *reflected* is a word you've already ruled out—perhaps because you're passing light *through* another medium.

In which case, the light could be considered to be **refracted** or **filtered**.

All from Merriam-Webster.

[**Refract**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refract):

> transitive verb
>
> **1 a** : to subject (something, such as a ray of light) to REFRACTON
>
> ([refraction](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refraction))
>
> 1 : deflection from a straight path undergone by a light ray or energy wave in passing obliquely from one medium (such as air) into another (such as glass) in which its velocity is different

[**Filter**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/filter):

> verb
>
> **1** : to subject to the action of a filter
>
> noun
>
> **2 a** : a device or material for suppressing or minimizing waves or oscillations of certain frequencies (as of electricity, light, or sound)
> **b** : a transparent material (such as colored glass) that absorbs light of certain wavelengths or colors selectively and is used for modifying light that reaches a sensitized photographic material — called also *color filter*

---

Alternatively, if you're not talking about the *technique* but the end result that shows moving light patterns, then you are describing [**animated**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/animated) light:

> **1 a** : endowed with life or the qualities of life : alive • *animated* creatures
> **b** : full of movement and activity • an *animated* crowd
> **c** : full of vigor and spirit : lively • an *animated* discussion
> **2** : having the appearance of something alive • an unusually *animated* piece of sculpture

Answer (score 2):

One term for this is ***[dappled](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dappled)*** (Cambridge). Sunlight passing through rustling leaves gives a dappled light.

Comment: I do love dappled and I'd thought of using that but not sure it's quite right for my context. I feel dappled has the feeling of slightly muted reflections or light and the materials I'm working with have quite strong colour reflections! Does that make sense??

Answer (score 1):

[**Glimmer**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glimmer):

> intransitive verb
>
> 1 a : to shine faintly or unsteadily - 
>       The candles *glimmered* in the windows.
>
> 1 b : to give off a subdued unsteady reflection - 
>       Her white satin dress *glimmered* in the dusk.
>
> 2 : to appear indistinctly with a faintly luminous quality

It's not exactly *dancing* as you requested, but it implies [*unsteady*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unsteady) - «marked by change or fluctuation; not uniform or even»

Answer (score 0):

**Shimmer**

shimmered; shimmering play  \ˈshi-mə-riŋ, ˈshim-riŋ\
intransitive verb

1 : to shine with a soft tremulous or fitful light : glimmer
2 : to reflect a wavering sometimes distorted visual image

transitive verb
: to cause to shimmer

Taken from: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shimmer

Comment: Hi Oliver! Your answer seems like you copied it from a web dictionary. Please add a link to your source :)

Answer (score 0):

The word **flitter** might suit your project. It doesn't indicate light but the word itself has a nice rhythm, lightness and sense of movement.